# How to get selected text of a select in a vue component

Tags: vue.js

I am using Laravel 7 and Vue.js 2.

I would like to catch the selected text when the user changes the selected option.

This is my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <title-form v-model="titleForm" :titleMessage="titleForm"></title-form>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <label for="devs" class="mt-3">Select a dev:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select required v-model="user.devs" class="form-control" id="devs" @change="onChangeDev($event)">
                <option v-for="dev in devs" :value="dev.id" :key="dev.id">
                    {{ dev.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <label for="devs">Assign a task to {{ selectedDev }}:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="assignTask()">Assign Task</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="devs"  class="mt-3">Remove a task from {{ selectedDev }}:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="removeTask()">Remove Task</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="devs"  class="mt-3">Show in progress task assigned to {{ selectedDev }}:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="showTasksInProgress()">Show In Progress Tasks</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="devs" class="mt-3">Show all cross-team projects (no need to select a dev):</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Cross-Team Projects</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="devs" class="mt-3">Show the PM of {{ selectedDev }}:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show PM</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import TitleForm from "./TitleForm.vue"

    export default {

        components: {
            'title-form': TitleForm

        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        },
        props: {
            devs: {
                type: Array,
                required: true,
                default: () => [],
            }
        },
        computed: {
            titleForm: function () {
                return "Welcome to Ticketsapp";
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                selectedDev: "the selected dev",
                user: {
                    devs: "",
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            assignTask() {
                alert(this.user.devs);
                if(this.user.devs !== "") {
                    window.location.href = "allocate/" + this.user.devs;
                } else {
                    alert("Select a dev");
                }
                
            },
            showTasksInProgress() {
                alert(this.user.devs);
                if(this.user.devs !== "") {
                    window.location.href = "inprogress/" + this.user.devs;
                } else {
                    alert("Select a dev");
                }
                
            },
            removeTask() {
                alert(this.user.devs);
                if(this.user.devs !== "") {
                    window.location.href = "remove/" + this.user.devs;
                } else {
                    alert("Select a dev");
                }
            },
            onChangeDev(e) {
                alert(e.target.text); //problem
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can imagine, I want to pass `dev.name`. I tried creating a method called `onChangeDev` passing the parameter `$event` but unfortunately when I alert the text I visualize `undefined`. So I am asking myself if there is a way to do that using Vue. Can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event value holds the value of an option. your code will alert the id of a user, which you set the value of an option (`:value="user.id"`) if you will alert like (`alert(e.target.value)`).

Value holds the value :)

Following code would do what you expect ;)

```
    onChangeDev(e) {
      const selectedDevId = e.target.value;
      const name = this.devs.filter((dev) => dev.id == selectedDevId)[0].name;
      alert(name);
    }
```

But it has O(N) time complexity due to filter mthod usage. Probably you can make it faster binding more data to the option and then fetching it from DOMElement...

Comment: It works but can you show me how I can make it more faster binding more data to the option and fetching from DOMElement?

Comment: Sure!!! 1) You may set the `:value="user.name"` then the e.target.value would be the name

Comment: 2) serialize your object, put this string as a value and then deserialize the value in your handler (https://pastebin.com/DvvXVb25)

Comment: 3) use your own approach of select html component. Build your component based on another html elements, which behaves exactly the same as native html select or even better. This approach is highly recomended whether you should customize select's layout

Comment: 4) use another people 3rd option made components (https://vue-select.org/ for example)       Sry for late answer. I'm too sleepy now :D

Comment: 5) Almost forgot to show DOMElements data-attributes implementation: https://pastebin.com/cXrf7jhg. It still has O(N) due to DOMElements iteration time complexity, but here N is not number of all devs, but number of html options elements (it's always less or equal to devs length).